# Moved local git folder and now its asking to stage most of my project files?

Tags: linux, git

I reinstalled my OS (KDE neon) and I thought why not backup my project git folder, before I reinstalled I made sure I commited any code and everything in my git project folder was up-to-date.

So after reinstalling, I moved my project back onto my PC from my backup drive and ran `git-status` and it wants to stage nearly all of my project?

What do I do? I don't want to commit all these files again when I have not editing any of them? Its nearly 800 files it wants to stage?

Comment: Did you backup the whole project directory or just the git folder?

Comment: The whole project with the .git folder.

Comment: do `git log --oneline` and check what was your last commit. If it is the one you did before backup then you can simply reset the project to that point  (you might want to first `git show commit_id` just to double-check)

Comment: Ok it turns out it is the same commit as the one on git hub, with the same id. How would I do a reset and if you don't mind, how would this mess up happen because I did not do anything to the project folder at all? Why would it ask to stage everything again?

Comment: Is the last commit the same one you took before backup (in which you commited all those files)?

Comment: Yes the last commit is the same, I even checked the hash. But I did not commit any of those 800+ files, before I did a backup of the project folder I just commited my last edit and it was not any of these 800 files. That is why I am confused because all I did it backup the project folder and moved it to my documents folder from my backup HDD, I just moved the folder from one place to another, just wondering how git would think all of those files need to be staged again. I have not touched any of them.

Comment: Your backup drive probably uses FAT filesystem, that screwed up you file permissions. In this case, these changed permissions are the reason, why Git thinks files have changed. The file contents itself probably haven't changed.

Comment: @ErkiA, That is what I assumed also.

Comment: @AymanNedjmeddine Ah, yes, good answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [reset](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified) your project using:

```
git reset --hard branch_name
```

This would lose any unstaged files.

Or you could [stash](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing) the changes:

```
git stash save 'msg'
```

This works like the previous one, but instead it saves the unstaged files in a separate *"memory"* (in case you need them later on).

Now, I may assume that the reason you got that situation in the first place is maybe when you restored your data back from the drive, the OS changed some properties on those files, stuff like creation/modification dates, permissions...etc. While the content of the files has not changed but the properties are. Still, `git` sees them as modified files.